# Can someone explain how the follwoing code calls football() method and when i run this script it get "football" as the result?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, closures, inversion-of-control

```
<?php
    class container{
        protected $bindings = [];
        public function bind($name, callable $resolver){
            $this->bindings[$name] = $resolver;
        }

        public function make($name){
            //calls football() method , there is no football() method
            return $this->bindings[$name]();
        }
    }

    $container = new container;
    $container->bind('Game', function(){
        return 'football';
    });

    print_r($container->make('Game'));
```

the code calls `football()` method, and returns  `" football "` as a result when i runs it . How does it run the `football()` method which does not exist ?

Comment: let's step through the process. First, we initialize the class. Then, we call the `bind()` method. This method stores the function that we pass it in the `$bindings` array with the key of `Game`. Then, we call the `make()` method. The `make()` method grabs the function that we stored earlier using the `bind()` method, and it then runs the function that we had stored. This function returns `"football"`. This means that the code never calls a method called `football()`, thus it doesn't need to exist. In fact, it doesn't call a method at all, just a stored function.

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica   the bind method accepts two arguments one is a variable another one is a closure , doesn't the closure function return a string ? which is football

Comment: @builder_dude Yes, so when the `make()` method calls that stored anonymous function/closure, it returns "football".

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica return $this->bindings[$name] ();   this line says ,$this->football () ; because       
$this->bindings[$name] is football , the code wont work if you take out the parentheses and i think the closure is returning an object not a string

Comment: @builder_dude No, `$this->bindings[$name]()` translates to `$this->bindings['Game']()` in this case. The string `football` is not passed anywhere except for the closure functions return.

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica  jus one doubt. why use parentheses at the end of this line ?                                                                                                               $this->bindings[$name]()

Comment: @builder_dude To run the function that is being returned by `$this->bindings['Game']`.